# create a table where one insert is a batch

Tags: postgresql

I want to create a table where one insert is a batch and if there are the same rows trying to insert again it should throw an error.

Here is a simple example.
This is one insert, if we try to insert these rows again it should throw an error.(It should not insert)

```
      col1   col2   col3  col4(ID)
row1   a      0.1    xyz   1
row2   b      0.2    abc   1
row3   c      0.3    pqr   1
```

Now I just changed insert little bit this should be as a new insert.

```
      col1   col2   col3   col4(ID)
row1   a      0.1    xyz    2
row2   b      0.211  abc    2
row3   c      0.3    pqr    2
```

I tried composite primary key but I was missing something. I'm seeing this error

> ERROR:  duplicate key value violates the unique constraint.

I want to throw an error when all three rows are repeated. If anything is changed in these 3 rows it should be a new insert.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add the `CREATE TABLE` statement including all indexes. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: so you want an error to be thrown only if all 3 rows are repeated or if any one is repeated ? Can you define an error case ?

Comment: I want to throw an error when all three rows are repeated. If anything is changed in these 3 rows it should be a new insert. @Aditya

Comment: Please share the current schema you are using and the insert/update query you are firing when you see this error

Comment: CREATE TABLE table2
(
    col1 integer NOT NULL,
    col2 text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    col3 real NOT NULL,
    col4 character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT table2_pkey PRIMARY KEY (col2, col3, col4),
    CONSTRAINT table2_col2_key UNIQUE (col2)
)

Comment: @Aditya can you help me with this.